# Storing user info file format in java

Tags: java, security

I am running a private server of an mmporg game, and the files are being stored locally in the vps with the file extention .p

Is it safe to do it that way, or I better use a database? If I don't use a database, what is the preferred method to store the info? What could go wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is far too broad. There are too many variables to consider. What type of data are you storing? How often? How much? What structure does it need to have? Etc... You should use whichever format is best for your purposes, which we can't guess at here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are handling large quantities of data (or expect you will in the future), a database is the way to go. Databases are highly optimised to allow storing large quantities of data in an efficient way and to allow fast querying of the data.

In terms of security, a database runs as a service on your system and authentication, encryption and backup mechanisms are usually offered with most products, which is a big plus as it will save you a lot of time and headaches.

Comment: Well yeah, they won't exceed 1000. Is there a better alternative for storing information locally in a different file format that will be a little bit more secure or that is used most of the time? .txt files could be reviewed, however, .p files couldn't so that is why I use it. For my future projects, is it stable to always use that?

Comment: A file extension will not in any way secure your information. The information will be stored the same in the system. If it is just for a small personal project, using files is fine. However, if you intend to deploy or scale the applicaton you should use a database. Concretely, from a low level perspective, a database is still just a collection of bytes on the system stored as files. However, the data is structured in such a way that it is highly efficient to store and manipulate it. It really depends on your application.